# extract frames from h264 encoder

Tags: video, h.264

how to extract frames from h264 encoder? i want to work with I frame bit streame.is there anybody tell me how can i get this frames. i use jm 15.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org).  Something like this should work:

ffmpeg -i foo.mp4 -r 1 -s WxH -f image2 foo-%03d.jpeg